# google search API always returns "Request contains an invalid argument"

Tags: google-api

Even the most basic query is returning

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The API key is valid; changing a character returns an "invalid API key" error instead

my call is:
`https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=test&key=[my api key]`

wondering if its just entirely broken... even the "try it out!" developer google page is returning the same invalid argument error

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22test%22%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass three required parameters for a custom search in [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)

You missed `Programmable Search Engine ID`

Three query [parameters] are required with each search request:

**API key** - Use the key query parameter to identify your application.

**Programmable Search Engine ID** - Use cx to specify the Programmable Search Engine you want to use to perform this search. The search engine must be created with the Control Panel Note: The Search Engine ID (cx) can be of different format (e.g. 8ac1ab64606d234f1)

**Search query** - Use the q query parameter to specify your search expression.

All other query parameters are optional.

##### Search URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?[parameters]
```

##### Demo search URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=test&key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve
```

##### Result

[image]

##### Your own search Engine

To create own `cx` value.

```
https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/create
```

[image]

[image]

##### Result of own cx value

[image]